# Is there any issue when deploying program on solana mainnet now?

Tags: solana-program

I'm using Solana v1.13.4 and anchor 0.25.0.

I deployed a program on mainnet successfully before but can't deploy it on mainnet now.

This is the error message.

I tried to deploy program using buffer account but still failed.

```
==================================================================================
Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
`solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
==================================================================================
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
==================================================================================
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as
the [BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana program write-buffer'.
Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the
[BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to `solana program drain`.
==================================================================================
```

The smart contract works well on devnet now.
It's really strange.
Why can't I deploy smart contract on mainnet?

Comment: What deploy command are you using for the maintnet? What version of devnet were you deploying to?

Comment: Also, did you make sure your signing address has enough SOl to deploy?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by add flag --with-compute-unit-price 1 (you can change 1 to any unit price you one, 1  = 1 microlamport). This flag will add priority fee for all your deployed tx. Just use the latest version solana cli 1.18.8
try this

> anchor build

> solana program deploy ./target/deploy/<..>.so --with-compute-unit-price 5